# Does Amazon Lightsail have remote desktop (GUI) with their Linux offering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, remote-desktop, amazon-lightsail

Lightsail allows RDP on their Windows instances, can I do the same with the Linux variant? Would like to run Selenium etc.

Comment: you need to install `X` or `xrdp` to gain access.

Comment: thanks @kintuparantu this helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install X or xrdp to gain access.

Comment: Thanks @kintuparantu

Eventually came up with this and a few more options that allowed me the same, as well as on EC2.

Here's an alternate approach

https://gist.github.com/pseudokool/c7707937f075dd74cfa905edc80de39b

One key addition being, you don't really need the proxy.